WinterCMS PHP renderPartial doesn't work after jQuery request
In plugin default.htm
<div id="tabs-2" class="tabs_block">
            {% partial 'companies' %}
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('body').on('click', '#create_new', function(){
            jQuery('form').request('onAllocate');
        });

        jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs() ;

        jQuery('body').on('click', '.block_user', function(){
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to block this user?'))
            {
                var alt = jQuery(this).attr("alt");
                jQuery('form').request('onUserBlock', {data: {alt: alt},});
            }
        });

    });
</script>


companies.htm partial
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email address</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for id, row in companies %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="block_user" alt="{{ row.user_id }}" data-dismiss="modal">[Block]</a>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

plugin Account.php
public function prepareVars()
    {
        $this->page['user'] = $this->user();
        $this->page['canRegister'] = $this->canRegister();
        $this->page['loginAttribute'] = $this->loginAttribute();
        $this->page['loginAttributeLabel'] = $this->loginAttributeLabel();
        $this->page['updateRequiresPassword'] = $this->updateRequiresPassword();
        $this->page['rememberLoginMode'] = $this->rememberLoginMode();

        #Log::info(json_encode($this->post_id));
        if($this->page->id == 'users' && $this->user())
        {
            $this->onCompanies();
        }
    }

public function onCompanies()
    {
        $usr = Auth::User()->getAttributes();

        $list = Array();

        $all = Db::select('select * from users_allocation where slave_id = ? and blocked < 1', [$usr['id']]);

        if (count($all) > 0) {
            foreach ($all as $a) {
                $company = Db::select('select * from users where id = ?', [$a->owner_id]);
                if (count($company) > 0) {
                    foreach ($company as $cp) {
                        $cid = md5($cp->id);

                        $list[$cid]['user_id'] = md5($a->owner_id);
                        $list[$cid]['name'] = $cp->name;
                        $list[$cid]['email'] = $cp->email;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->page['companies'] = $list;
        return [
            '#tabs-1' => $this->renderPartial('companies')
        ];
    }

jQuery('form').request('onUserBlock', {data: {alt: alt},}); calls onUserBlock function in Account.php
public function onUserBlock()
    {
        $data = post();
        $id = $data['alt'];
        $usr = Auth::User()->getAttributes();

        $company = Db::select('select * from users_allocation where  md5(owner_id) = ? and slave_id = ? and blocked = 1', [$id, $usr['id']]);
        
        if (count($company) > 0) {
            Flash::error('This company already blocked.');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Db::update('update users_allocation set blocked = 1 where md5(owner_id) = ? and slave_id = ?', [$id, $usr['id']]);

            $this->onCompanies();

            Flash::success(Lang::get(/**/'Company successfully blocked and will not able to send you invitation.'));
        }
    }

The problem is, that when prepareVars calls onCompanies on page load, then code is rendering HTML, but when onCompanies is called from onUserBlock, then code doesn't re-render HTML.
Any idea why?
I tried to put $this->onCompanies(); before and after Flash::success, but no luck.

Double check AJAX Framework is Initialized properly

Look to the browser's inspector tool. Check the console tab for possible javascript errors, and the network tab to ensure the ajax calls are happening, and if they are, check the response information.

in onUserBlock(), you need to return the result of onCompanies()

in onUserBlock(), there is $this->onCompanies(); which should work same as in prepareVars(), when calls onCompanies(), but it doesn't work when onCompanies() called from onUserBlock()
